# how to use non-database variables in doctrine model

Tags: php, doctrine

I have two database fields `$object->value` and `$object->max_value` and want to store the proportion in `$object->percent_value` without having a db field for it.

Is there a way to do this in a doctrine model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have an `ObjectBase` class (obviously named something different) where the database attributes are defined.  There should also be an `Object` class.  Here you can define the `percent_value` attribute which calculates and returns the percentage on the fly.